# Phone call within react native

Tags: react-native

Is there a way within react-native or some library that would allow the app to make a phone call within a custom UI & record the call? Ive seen react-native-communications but that redirects and uses the phones UI to make the call.

Comment: Is this for android only?

Comment: @10101010 no it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cloning and running this repo. It does what you are trying to do. 
https://github.com/aryaminus/RN-voice-video-call/tree/HttpApiSetup